# Can I use a generic to output different data types in different ways?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this simple code:

```
static void WriteToLogFile(string LogFileName, string S, bool AppendCRLF = false)

// Todo: make a generic, output formatting dependent on data type?

{
    if (AppendCRLF)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(S);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(S);
    }
}
```

The calling routine is responsible to convert any data to string.

What I'd like to do now is being able to pass any data type, and make the output dependent on the data type I pass. E.g. if I pass a DateTime, I want it formatted using some template, if I pass a string I want it enclosed in double quotes, and so forth.

I know that I can overload WriteToLogFile for each and every data type, but I wonder whether there is a solution using generics? Something like this:

```
static void WriteToLogFile<T>(string LogFileName, ref T X, bool AppendCRLF = false)

{
...
    switch (TypeOf(X))
    {
    case "string": Console.Write('"' + X + '"'); break;
    case "DateTime": Console.Write(X.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); break;
    default: Console.Write(X.toString());
    }
....
}
```

Is such a construct possible in C#?

Comment: If you need a specific behavior for every type, overloaded method seems to be a best choice. Or use `switch` with pattern if only output is needed

Comment: a method that that does different things for **specific** types isn´t very **generic**, is it? So, no, generics won´t help you. Use overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use types in [pattern matching with switch statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements):

```
switch (X)
{
     case string s: Console.Write('"' + s + '"'); break;
     case DateTime dt: Console.Write(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); break;
     default: Console.Write(X.toString());
}
```

Also in you case it seems that you can leverage from this style of pattern matching:

```
var toLog = X switch
{
    string s => $"{s}",
    DateTime dt => dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),
    _ => X.ToString()
};

if (AppendCRLF)
{
    Console.WriteLine(toLog);
}
else
{
    Console.Write(toLog);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was quick, I hadn't even finished editing my question! I'll check this out, and accept. Thanks!